# Favorite Questions and answers from fourth quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

This has now been [posted](https://thesffblog.com/2020/01/highlights-from-2019-4th-quarter/).

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2019 through December 31th 2019.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

From the previous post:

> There were 19 bounty awards for 2625 [sweet sweet rep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8uM0zOBuSw).

Answer (score 6):

[Was Jumanji intended to be a co-op game?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224577/21154)

Always bugged me watching the movie. It's always nice to see lesser-asked-about series on the site, too.

Answer (score 4):

Favorite Question and Answer Combo: [How does AT-AT deploy troops?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221820/how-does-at-at-deploy-troops)

Because sometimes a premise is actually [as silly as we thought it was](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221820/how-does-at-at-deploy-troops#comment606113_221820)...

Answer (score 3):

I have to mention this answer, to which I awarded a bounty for the first time in a few years:

[Time travel to the crucifixion of Jesus and changing the past](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/224026/31394)

The title describes a common enough trope (the question body has more details), but the amount of work that went into the answer is really something else:

> Well, after I spent a couple of hours locating the stored boxes in the attic, unpacking them, and going through the individual issues one by one, I managed to find it (in full compliance with Murphy's law, the sought issues were near the end of my unordered stack)...
>
> It is a Greek translation of a novelette ... originally written in Spanish ... but first published in French translation ... No wonder google searches went unfruitful, as it seems it has never been translated into English.